# Java FTPClient Stuck

Tags: java, ftp, file-transfer, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I'm trying to download a file from my ftp server, but it gets stuck while retrieving them. I'm using `commons-net-3.6.jar`

**Things I've Noticed**

When I use `ftpClient.enterRemotePassiveMode();` 
 I can see in the FileZilla server interface that the progress of the download for the connection stuck at 76% (688,128 bytes)

When I use `ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();` 
 I can see in the FileZilla server interface that the progress of the download for the connection stuck at 96% (884,736 bytes)

What's interesting is that in these two modes it always gets stuck at that exact same amount of bytes no matter what the file is. If the file size is larger than 884,736 or 688,128 it just gets stuck.

It works perfectly for files less that 884,736 bytes in LocalPassiveMode and 688,128 bytes in RemotePassiveMode.

I've tried downloading from a different server and it didn't work so its definitely not a server related issue.

**My Code**

```
public class FTPDownload {

private List<BufferedImage> imageList;
private boolean wasConnected;


public void getFiles(String orderRootDirectory){

    wasConnected = true;

    imageList = new ArrayList<>();
    FTPConnection con = new FTPConnection(); // to get the FTP Credentials
    con.readData();
   try {
       FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
       ftpClient.connect(con.getServerIp());
       ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

       ftpClient.login(con.getUsername(), con.getPassword());
       ftpClient.setAutodetectUTF8(true);
       ftpClient.setBufferSize(1024 * 1024); // tried with and without this no luck there

       wasConnected = ftpClient.isConnected();

       FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles(orderRootDirectory);

       for (FTPFile file : files) {
           String details = file.getName();


           if (file.isDirectory()) {
               details = "[" + details + "]";
           }

           String totalFilePath = orderRootDirectory+"/"+file.getName();



           InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(totalFilePath);  // stuck over here

           System.out.println(ftpClient.completePendingCommand());
           System.out.println(ftpClient.getReplyString());

           System.out.println("Reading File...");
           long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
           ImageIO.setUseCache(false);
           BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(inputStream);


           long end=System.currentTimeMillis();
           System.out.println("time="+(end-start));


           imageList.add(bimg);

           details += "\t\t" + file.getSize();
           details += "\t\t" + file.getName();
           System.out.println(details);
       }

       System.out.println(imageList.size());

       ftpClient.logout();
       ftpClient.disconnect();
   }catch (Exception e){

       e.printStackTrace();
       wasConnected = false;

   }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FTPClient#retrieveFileStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFileStream(java.lang.String)) states that:

> You must close the InputStream when you finish reading from it. The
>   InputStream itself will take care of closing the parent data
>   connection socket upon being closed.

And

> To finalize the file transfer you must call completePendingCommand and
>   check its return value to verify success. If this is not done,
>   subsequent commands may behave **unexpectedly**.

---

Calls should be *finalized* using `completePendingCommand`, right now you're executing that method *before* finalizing (you're reading from the `inputStream` after you've called `completePendingCommand`).

Also you're not closing your `inputStream` which it specifically states.

---

To fix your issues do something like this, where we first close the `inputStream` and then call `completePendingCommand`, all of this should happen *after* we've read the `inputStream`.

```
InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(totalFilePath);

BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(inputStream);

inputStream.close();
if (!ftpClient.completePendingCommand()) {
    // Throw some error or do something, file transfer failed
}
```